# TypeScript globally vs locally

Tags: typescript

I really don't understand about installing typescript globally or locally.

1. What is the different to install typescript globally and locally?
2. Any cons and/or pros?
3. What context is relevant to use globally or locally?

Thank you!

```
* To install TypeScript globally, run:
$ npm i typescript -g

*And to install locally, run:
$ npm i typescript --save-dev
```

Comment: Consider this: you want to work on two projects. One is older and uses TS 3.9 or whatever. The other uses a newer version of TS. Which one would be easier - having one single global version of TS for both, or two different versions of TS one for each?

Comment: Installing it in your project makes sure that whenever someone clones your project and runs `npm install`, they will also have typescript, required to run different tasks. It also makes sure that everyone gets the same version of Typescript.

Comment: Thank you! I have some questions.
When you execute the code "$ npm i typescript -g", does it take the latest version or do you have a defined version of typescript in relation to globally?